# what are alternatives for CString methods of GetBuffer and ReleaseBuffer in MinGW?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, cstring

I found a nice example how to play with folder selecting dialog: http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip70.htm - and all this is working except of this example using CString which I can't have on MinGW because it doesn't have `stdafx.h`. So I must use either string or char*.

But here the problem is that this example uses CString methods: `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer` which I don't have in string object. Is there any other method of passing folder name to folder selection window ?

Comment: I thought `stdafx.h` was for precompiled headers, not CString.

Comment: CString is part of MFC not the standard library. You will need to install the Windows SDK (if it's still included) to get it.

Comment: Ok, and if CString is out of question, are there any alternative methods ?

Comment: @rsk82 `std::string` and `std::wstring`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: yes, but I mean the methods, that is `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer`... what are their counterparts in string object ?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with the Windows API and buffers, you can use `std::vector<BYTE>` for bytes and `std::vector<TCHAR>` for strings. (`TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t` if UNICODE is defined and `char` otherwise. This way the code works for both UNICODE and ANSI). When instantiating the vector, give it a size to allocate memory:

```
// can hold MAX_PATH TCHARs, including terminating '\0'
std::vector<TCHAR> buffer(MAX_PATH);
```

Now you can treat is almost exactly like a buffer of TCHARs allocated with new or created on the stack.

```
BROWSEINFO bi = {0};
bi.pszDisplayName = &buffer[0];
```

However, `buffer.size()` will always return the full vector length. If you need to know the length of the string stored within the vector, or want to use string related methods,
you can copy it to a `std::string`:

```
if( LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi) ) {
    // this way it works for both UNICODE and ANSI:
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> folderName(&buffer[0]);

    if( SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl,&buffer[0]) ) {
        MessageBox(0, &buffer[0], folderName.c_str(), MB_OK);
    }
    // TODO: free pidl with IMalloc* obtained through SHGetMalloc() 
}
```

Since `std::string` is just another contiguous container, you could (ab)use that instead of the vector. However, `size()` will return the number of elements stored in the string, even if they are `\0`. You would have to `resize()` the string to the first occurrence of `\0` (that is what CString::ReleaseBuffer() does) which is done automatically when you assign the buffer to the string in the above example. Because a string is not meant to be used as a buffer (even if it is technically possible) i strongly recommend using the vector approach.

Comment: Still would recommend `std::vector<BYTE>` in case signedness matters. +1

Answer (score 0):

With `std::string` you have a read-only access to the underlying representation by using `c_str()`, but nothing else.

In your case, I think the only option is to use some old-fashioned memory management, and then copy the result in a `std::string`.